# Why this `cmovnel` does not work as intended?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

Please test out this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned f(unsigned x) {
    unsigned res;
    asm(
        "movl $4, %0\n\t"
        "testl %1, %1\n\t"
        "cmovnel %1, %0\n\t"
        : "=r"(res)
        : "r"(x)
        : "cc"
    );
    return res;
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        printf("%u, ", f(i));
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, the function `f(x)` is basically:

```
unsigned f(unsigned x) {
    return f ? f : 4;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes it returns the correct result, sometimes it does not.

If you run the above code on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/), you can get the intended behavior. It prints 4, 1, 2, 3 ...

But if you run it on [programiz online compiler](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/), you will get 4, 4, 4, 4 ...

When I ran it locally, I got 4, 4, 4, 4 ...

What is the problem with this piece of code? Thank you.

Comment: The usual case of writing output before consuming the input so if the compiler picks the same register it won't work. Use an early clobber modifier.

Comment: @Jester Did not know about that. Tested the modified version out and it works. Thank you!